# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V - Flink on EMR

Tags: scala, apache-flink, amazon-emr

- I am trying to run a Flink (v 1.13.1) application on EMR ( v
  5.34.0).
- My Flink application uses Scallop(v 4.1.0) to parse the arguments passed.
- Scala version used for Flink application is
  2.12.7.

I keep getting below error when I submit the flink application to the cluster. Any clue or help is highly appreciated.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
at org.rogach.scallop.Scallop.<init>(Scallop.scala:63)
at org.rogach.scallop.Scallop$.apply(Scallop.scala:13)
```

Comment: I can't quickly find which Scala version Scallop is using, but I'm wondering if Scallop is using a later version of Scala then Flink actually supports.

Comment: Thank you. yeah, trying to get that information. Once I have that information, I believe I can adjust scallop version accordingly and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by downgrading Scala to 2.11. Flink 1.13.1 Scala shell REPL on EMR mentioned scala version 2.11.12 hence downgraded to that version of Scala and this problem has disappeared.

Comment: Keep in mind that Scala 2.11 support is removed and won't be there in future versions of Flink.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate the information. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Hi, while on topic, I need to get JNI call working from Flink next, would you be able to suggest/advice on that ? I can open up another question if you think that is more appropriate.